# Python generate_blob_sas doesn't create right SAS token (failed on copy operation in azcopy)

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

It's my first question at such cool resource.

**Description of a goal:** I need to copy from one Azure storage account to another. ... Not only this, but this part doesn't  work for me now.

**Problem:** If generate token with generate_blob_sas you will have in azcopy operation:

> INFO: Authentication failed, it is either not correct, or expired, or does not have the correct permission -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.13.1-0.20210914164749-2d6cd3e07548/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
> ===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=AuthenticationFailed) =====
> Description=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

If insert manually created token on Azure portal - works fine.

Why I use azcopy inside of Python, because I have structure like this:

```
.
|
|└── Folder1
|    ├── file1.json
|    ├── file2.json
|    ├── file3.json
|    ├── file4.json
|    ├── file5.son
|    └── Folder2
|        ├── fileswithsomenames1.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames2.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames3.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames4.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames5.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames6.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames7.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames8.html
|        ├── fileswithsomenames9.html
|        └── fileswithsomenames10.html
└──receipt.json (this file will be eachtime but with different content)
```

A number of files will be different in each situation. And I need to work ahead with files from target blob.
I didn't find understandable description how to copy from store1/conteiner1/{var.name}-blob to var.name-store2/conteainer1/ all content including many folders. Almost all descriptions and manuals for 1 blob file.

**My code:**

```
code to authorise and get storage account name and string 
...
customer_name = 'abc-qa'
...
container_name_source = "container1"
blob_name_source = customer_name+"-blobfolder1/blobfolder2"

container_name_target = customer_name+"-bl"
blob_name_target = "/"

# Function to generate sas for source blob
def get_blob_sas_source(account_name_source,account_key_1_source, container_name_source, blob_name_source):
    sas_blob_source = generate_blob_sas(account_name=account_name_source, 
                                container_name=container_name_source,
                                blob_name=blob_name_source,
                                account_key=account_key_1_source,
                                permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                                expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
    return sas_blob_source

sas_blob_source = get_blob_sas_source(account_name_source,account_key_1_source, container_name_source, blob_name_source)
url_blob_source = 'https://'+account_name_source+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name_source+'/'+blob_name_source+'?'+sas_blob_source

# Function to generate sas for target blob
def get_blob_sas_target(account_name_target,account_key_1_target, container_name_target, blob_name_target):
    sas_blob_target = generate_blob_sas(account_name=account_name_target, 
                                container_name=container_name_target,
                                blob_name=blob_name_target,
                                account_key=account_key_1_target,
                                permission=BlobSasPermissions(add=True, create=True, write=True, tag=False, delete_previous_version=True),
                                expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
    return sas_blob_target

sas_blob_target = get_blob_sas_target(account_name_target,account_key_1_target, container_name_target, blob_name_target)
print(sas_blob_target)
url_blob_target = 'https://'+account_name_target+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name_target+'/?'+sas_blob_target




#copy seed-data folder from account_name_source/container1/customer_name+"-blobfolder1/blobfolder2" to account_name_target/customer_name+"-bl"
cmd = f"azcopy copy '{url_blob_source}' '{url_blob_target}' --recursive=True"
print(str(cmd))
results = subprocess.run(
    str(cmd), shell=True, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
print(results.stdout)
```

Result if gen manually
'sp=rl&st=2022-04-14T14:29:48Z&se=2022-04-14T22:29:48Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig={token}'

Rusult if gen over generate_blob_sas

'se=2022-04-14T17%3A18%3A48Z&sp=r&sv=2020-10-02&sr=b&sig={token}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is failing with the SAS token generated programmatically is because it is missing `List` permission. If you look at the working SAS token, it has both `Read` and `List` permissions (`sp=rl`) whereas the non-working SAS token only has `Read` permission (`sp=r`).

Another issue is that in your code you are generating SAS token for the blob (`sr=b`) whereas the working SAS token is for the container (`sr=c`). This is for both source and target SAS token.

To fix this:

- Create the SAS token with both `Read` and `List` permissions.
- Create the SAS token for the container instead of blob. For this, you will need to use `generate_container_sas`.

Once you do these two things, you should not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code for me now with generate_container_sas from access policy:

```
# Here code where I get storage account name and key. And Authentication by SPN which in KV.  
...
customer_name = 'abc-qa'
container_name_source = "conteiner1"
blob_name_source = customer_name+"-blobfolder1/blobfolder2"

container_name_target = customer_name+"-bl"
blob_name_target = "blobfolder2"


from datetime import datetime, timedelta

connection_string_source = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName='+account_name_source+';AccountKey='+blob_key_1_source+';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
connection_string_target = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName='+account_name_target+';AccountKey='+blob_key_1_target+';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'


# Instantiate a BlobServiceClient using a connection string
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client_source = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string_source)
blob_service_client_target = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string_target)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client_source = blob_service_client_source.get_container_client(container_name_source)
container_client_target = blob_service_client_target.get_container_client(container_name_target)

# [START set_container_access_policy]
# Create access policy Soure
from azure.storage.blob import AccessPolicy, ContainerSasPermissions
access_policy_source = AccessPolicy(permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, list=True),
                              expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),
                              start=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1))

identifiers_source = {'rl': access_policy_source}

# Create access policy Target
from azure.storage.blob import AccessPolicy, ContainerSasPermissions
access_policy_target = AccessPolicy(permission=ContainerSasPermissions(write=True),
                              expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),
                              start=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1))

identifiers_target = {'w': access_policy_target}

# Set the access policy on the container
container_client_source.set_container_access_policy(signed_identifiers=identifiers_source)
container_client_target.set_container_access_policy(signed_identifiers=identifiers_target)

# [END set_container_access_policy]

# [START get_container_access_policy]
policy_source = container_client_source.get_container_access_policy()
policy_source = container_client_target.get_container_access_policy()
# [END get_container_access_policy]

# [START generate_sas_token]
# Use access policy to generate a sas token Source
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas

sas_token_source = generate_container_sas(
    container_client_source.account_name,
    container_client_source.container_name,
    account_key=container_client_source.credential.account_key,
    policy_id='rl'
)
print(sas_token_source)
# [END generate_sas_token]

# Use access policy to generate a sas token Source
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas

sas_token_target = generate_container_sas(
    container_client_target.account_name,
    container_client_target.container_name,
    account_key=container_client_target.credential.account_key,
    policy_id='w'
)
print(sas_token_target)
# [END generate_sas_token]

#copy seed-data folder from stcorpmainstorage/seed-data/$(name of env)-seed-data/seed-data to $(name of env)store
cmd = f"azcopy copy 'https://{account_name_source}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name_source}/{blob_name_source}?{sas_token_source}' 'https://{account_name_target}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name_target}/?{sas_token_target}' --recursive=True"
results = subprocess.run(
    str(cmd), shell=True, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
print(results.stdout)

...
# Here code to work with target blob and next steps.
```

I hope it will be useful for someone.